# No such file 'config/database.yml' on Heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, rack

My app is a Ruby rack app. When my Heroku app starts it breaks because

> /app/config.ru:8:in `read': No such file or directory - config/database.yml (Errno::ENOENT)

Why does this happen? I understood Heroku is meant to create this file  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar-migration

> The database credentials will still be configured automatically: at slug compile time, a config/database.yml that parses the DATABASE_URL from the environment will be written into the app.

Frustratingly the doc at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby doesn't explain about `database.yml`

Comment: Are you expecting/wanting Heroku to create this file? If so, do you have a `config` directory in your app (with a file in so git commits it)?

Comment: Thanks matt. Committed my own `config/database.yml`, now Heroku replaces it at slug time with its own. Weird. What if I wanted to keep my `database.yml` private?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears Heroku only creates its `config/database.yml` if you have a folder `config` under source control. Not explained in docs.

Comment: I don’t think you need the `database.yml` file, [just the `config` dir](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby/blob/v38/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb#L443). If there’s nothing else in your config dir try adding an empty `.gitkeep` file so that the dir gets pushed to Heroku.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the first thing - heroku does not use database.yml file. By default rails app loading it from config/ directory automatically. And it's no need to load it manually in config.ru. If you want to use in heroku PosgreSQL - just add add-on. Heroku wil do all other things to link your app and db. If you want to use external MySQL server you should use Amazon RDS add-on

```
heroku addons:add amazon_rds url=mysql2://user:pass@dbhost/dbname
```

By this you can use any db. I use GoDaddy mysql bases through the Amazon RDS add-on.

Any way, the problem in your config.ru 8th line something like

```
read 'config/database.yml'
```

Delete it and look other ways that not conflicted with heroku

Good luck

Comment: My app is vanilla Rack (Sinatra or Camping), not Rails

Comment: ow sorry. Any way: "The database credentials will still be configured automatically: at slug compile time, a config/database.yml that parses the DATABASE_URL from the environment will be written into the app." Try to comment that string and try to start before add to heroku config variables with db host name user and pass

Comment: as I said- heroku automatically compiling file for db connect. No need to set it up manually